# Parameters of the Reed-Muller code

Tags: coding-theory

I saw the parameters of RM$_{m,t}$ are $[n,k,d]=[2^m,\sum_{i=0}^{t}{m \choose i},2^{m-t}]$ I can't work out why the dimension is $\sum_{i=0}^{t}{m \choose i}$. A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codewords of a Reed-Muller code correspond to polynomials
of degree at most $t$ in $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ with the restriction
that each variable appears to at most the first power. The dimension
of these under the extra condition that each term has $i$ $x_j$s is
$\binom mi$.

Comment: The (vectors corresponding to) monomials form a base of that size. We can pick $i$ variables from $m$, to form those monomials.